# Ошибка в парсинге JSON файла SWIFT

Tags: json, swift, swift4

Я пытаюсь запарсить JSON, но у меня на выходе получаются nil значения.

```
struct Rest1: Codable {
    struct Name: Codable {
        var about: String?
        var site: String?
        var phone: String?
    }
}

struct Rest: Codable {
    var osaka: More?
    var sicilliya: More?
    var blinnaya: More?
}

struct More: Codable {
    var about: String
    var site: String
    var phone: String
}

let JSON =
"""
{
    "Osaka": {
        "about": "__blank__",
        "site": "www.osaka.ru",
        "phone": "81231231234"
    },
    "Siciliya": {
        "about": "__blank__",
        "site": "www.siciliya.ru",
        "phone": "84564564567"
    },
    "Blinnaya": {
        "about": "__blank__",
        "site": "www.blinnaya.ru",
        "phone": "86786786789"
    }
}
"""

let dt = JSON.data(using: .utf8)

do {
    let jsdecode1 = try JSONDecoder().decode(Rest1.self, from: dt!)
    let jsdecode = try JSONDecoder().decode(Rest.self, from: dt!)
    print(jsdecode1)
    print(jsdecode)
}
catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

Вот вывод данных:

```
Rest1()
Rest(osaka: nil, sicilliya: nil, blinnaya: nil)
```

Не могли бы вы подсказать, где я допустил ошибку, т.к. я сам не могу найти мою оплошность.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас должны совпадать именования в структуре данных с названиями полей в json, иначе нужно прописать алиасы.

Попробуйте так:

```
struct Rest: Decodable {
    var Osaka: More?
    var Sicilliya: More?
    var Blinnaya: More?
}
struct More: Decodable {
    var about: String
    var site: String
    var phone: String
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо